# What's the difference between ActionBar and create vertical layout for ActionBar

Tags: android

First sry for my amateur question

When we want to make an Actionbar, we can use AppCompat or libs(like ActionBarSherlock & ...), and when we want just add any widget(like Button-ImageView & ...), we have to add a lot of codes...

But we can create vertical layout (height:50dip) in all of Activities and use it as the Actionbar...(It's very simpler than use standard ActionBar) 
`I mean is: why we shouldn't do this...?`

thanks... :)

Comment: Yeah that's fine, i'm using that method too for a toolbar. mine is a table layout and looks like a normal toolbar, Its just that a toolbar is build to be a toolbar and has helper functions and all the mod cons, but creating a custom toolbar that mimics the normal toolbar is no problem.

Comment: Android itself doesn't recommend to use actionbar like you want to.. Android recommend to use action bar for top header in you app. You can use toolbar in AppCompact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBar comes with a useful [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html), which allows you to add an app/menu icon to the left, and title, tabs, and action icons, as well as skinning options via themes, in a way that looks consistent across all your Activities and Fragments.

ActionBar also behaves (mostly) gracefully across different devices formats, keeping icon, title and action items in a uniform layout, while hiding excess action icons into a menu on the right. If you develop your custom implementation, you need to test that it doesn't break across Android versions and devices.